# Links are not correct after loading header & footer outside Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have an external webpage say "test.php" and I have loaded the site header & footer block from the Magento framework to use as a header & footer in this external page. Everything is working fine except url links. This is what I have done so far:

```
include 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

umask(0);
Mage::app()->loadArea('frontend');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
$layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');

//load default xml layout handle and generate blocks
$layout->getUpdate()->load('default');
$layout->generateXml()->generateBlocks();

//load header
$headBlock = $layout->getBlock('head');
$headerBlock = $layout->getBlock('header');
echo $headBlock->toHtml() . $headerBlock->toHtml();

// load footer
$footerBlock = $layout->getBlock('footer');
echo $footerBlock->toHtml();
```

The problem is url link generated at this page includes test.php in its base url.

Say I have a link "About Us". The url generated for this link in magento is "http://localhost/myapp/index.php/about.html" But url generated for the same link on test.php is "http://localhost/myapp/test.php/about.html".

How this can be resolved?

OR

Is there any other way to load theme's header and footer?

OR

Is there any way I can load test.php as an iframe within magento and pass url parameters?

Comment: localhost links will not work in other computers, so pleaase add screenshots

Comment: I've added links to show the difference i.e. how the index.php is replaced with test.php outside magento. May be it's about base url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding below lines to the first of script worked for me.

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php',        $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
```

So, the final script looks like:

```
include 'app/Mage.php';

//Added
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);

Mage::app();

umask(0);
Mage::app()->loadArea('frontend');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
$layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');

//load default xml layout handle and generate blocks
$layout->getUpdate()->load('default');
$layout->generateXml()->generateBlocks();

//load header
$headBlock = $layout->getBlock('head');
$headerBlock = $layout->getBlock('header');
echo $headBlock->toHtml() . $headerBlock->toHtml();

// load footer
$footerBlock = $layout->getBlock('footer');
echo $footerBlock->toHtml();
```